# Dual boot windows 8 and ubundu not see partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I'm trying to install both operating systems on dual boot, but ubuntu does not see the hd with two partitions only full hd.

In windows explorer have 2 partitions on ubuntu partitioner have only one

Answer (score 0):

This symptom is most often caused by one of two things:

- Leftover RAID data
- A damaged partition table

The first problem typically requires recovery by deleting the stray RAID data (I don't recall the command offhand, but it's a simple one-line command) and/or disabling RAID options in your firmware.

If it's a Master Boot Record (MBR) disk, a damaged partition table can often be repaired with my [FixParts program.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) If the computer shipped with Windows 8, though, it almost certainly uses the GUID Partition Table (GPT) instead of MBR, in which case you'll need to post more details, such as the output of `sgdisk -p -v /dev/sda`, as typed from a [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) or [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) boot.